# Sony Vaio VGN-FE41S (WebCam)

Tags: hardware

Hello I have a Sony Vaio VGN-FE41S  laptop , with  a webcam Richoh. 
Searching the Internet, use the driver r5u870 .

Elementary OS Freya (Ubuntu) has not included.

How can you add the module r5u870 ?

Cheers

Comment: Does your webcam work?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like there are unclear copyright issues regarding the webcam firmware.
Installing the [firmware loader for cameras based on Ricoh R5U87x chipsets](https://launchpad.net/~r5u87x-loader/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/) with the following steps may solve your problem:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:r5u87x-loader/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r5u87x
sudo /usr/share/r5u87x/r5u87x-download-firmware.sh
```

**Please create a backup before trying this solution, it also may break your system!**